# sql event delete from table if time passed

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a sql event for my database that removes a user's login token if the user's last `seen` is 15 minutes less than the current time. My `login_tokens` table has `id,token,user_id,date` columns, the users table has `id,name,seen` columns. The code I tried is

```html
BEGIN
DELETE FROM login_tokens WHERE login_tokens.user_id = users.id AND users.seen + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE < NOW();
END
```

SQL tells me that I cannot use `+ INTERVAL 15 MINUTES < NOW()` what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't invoked users..

Comment: And it's MINUTE not minutes. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html and

Comment: @P.Salmon I changed it but it's still not working

Comment: @P.Salmon what do you mean by invoking users

Comment: you need to join a table to access the columns of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a proper *inner join*:

```sql
DELETE login_tokens FROM
login_tokens JOIN users ON login_tokens.user_id = users.id
WHERE users.seen + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE < NOW();
```

or equivalently because this is an ***inner*** join:

```sql
DELETE login_tokens FROM
login_tokens JOIN users ON
    login_tokens.user_id = users.id AND users.seen + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE < NOW();
```